# Slider showing hidden elements when window re-sizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider that shifts between dividers that i'm facing two problems with, when window re-sizing

1. The first problem is that the dividers that are hidden, (the content of the slider that is not showing) are appearing when re-sizing.
   http://postimg.org/image/pydr005qb/
2. The buttons of the slider are not adapting to the window re-sizing, thus not keeping up their position above the slider when it reacts to the window re-sizing.
   http://postimg.org/image/pydr005qb/

PS:

- The slider's position is below the logo to the right of the menu, starting at the same level of the first element in the menu.
- I provided an image for the above problems because the malfunctions might not appear in the jsfiddle result tab.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/p8wdwa30/

HTML:

```
 <div id="logo" class="logo" ><img src="logo.png"/></div>

        <div id="menu" class="menu">
        <ul class="headlines">
              <li id="item1"><button>Aaaaaaaa</button></li>
            <li id="item2"><button>Bbbbbbb</button></li>
            <li id="item3"><button>Cccccccc        </button></li>
            <li id="item4"><button>Ddddddd         </button></li>
            <li id="item5"><button>Eeeeeeee Eee.   </button></li>
            <li id="item6"><button>Fffffffff       </button></li>
            <li id="item7"><button>Ggggggggg       </button></li>
        </ul>
        </div>


      <div id="container">
            <div id="first" class="inner-container">
                <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="slider-container">
    <div id="nav">
        <p id="prev">&lt;</p>
        <p id="next">&gt;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-view-area">
    <div id="mask">
        <div id="item11" class="item"> <a name="item11"></a>

            <div class="content">
                <a caption="A tableyv" rel="Sold" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="thumb1" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/4_b.jpg"><img id="image0" src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/4_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

<a caption="A table" rel="Sold" class="fancybox hidden" data-fancybox-group="thumb1" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg"><img id="image1" src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item22" class="item">
            <div class="content">
                <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="slot2" />
                <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item33" class="item">
            <div class="content">
                <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="slot2" />
                <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
html {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #545454;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #222;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}
h2 {
    margin-top: 1.3em;
}
.custom-class {
    text-align: right;
    margin-top:-130px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
b, strong {
    font-weight: 600;
}
samp {
    display: none;
}
img {
    -webkit-animation: colorize 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .78, .36) 1;
    animation: colorize 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .78, .36) 1;
    background: transparent;
    border-style:none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    margin: 1.3em auto;
    max-width: 95%;
}
.logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:40px;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-top: 8px;
    text-align:center;
    border-style: none;
}
.menu li {
    position: relative;
    top: 180px;
    left: 0px;
}
#item7 {
    transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    margin-left:105px 
}
#item6 {
    transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    margin-left: 95px;
}
#item5 {
    transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
#item4 {
    transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    margin-left: 123px;
}
#item3 {
    transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    margin-left: 113px;
}
#item2 {
    transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    margin-left: 130px;
}
#item1 {
    transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    margin-left: 117px;
}

#item1>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item2>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item3>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item4>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item5>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item6>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item7>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}

.permahover li {
    opacity: 1;
    left: -40%;
}
.headlines li {
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:#000000;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#first
{  display: none;
     width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    top: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;


}

#first img 
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 17%;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}



@-webkit-keyframes colorize {
    0% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    }
}

@keyframes colorize {
    0% {
        filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    100% {
        filter: grayscale(0%);
    }
}

}

<!-- slider css-->

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: px 0;
}

#slider-container {
    padding: 20px 50px;
    height: 300px;
    top:-18%;
    left: 50px;
    width: 700px;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.slider-view-area {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}

#nav p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 31px;
    left: 300px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:grey;

}
#prev {
    left: 40px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#next {
    right: 40px;
    margin-right: -370px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#mask {
    width: 50000px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

.item {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
}
.content img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 17%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:  10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.content {
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    top: 30px;
    left: 
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}
.content a {
    position: relative;
    top: -17px;
    left: 170px;
}
.selected {
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
```

}

JQUERY:

```
$(".menu").on("click", function () {
    $(".menu").addClass('permahover');
});


var $li = $('.headlines li').click(function () {
    var state = !$(this).hasClass('active');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active', state);

    $li.removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active', state);
});

  $(document).on('click','#item1', function()
{ 
    $("#container").fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $(".inner-container").hide();
        $("#first").show();
        $("#container").fadeIn(6000);
    });

});


$(document).ready(function () {
    var newItem = 0;
    var itemCount = $('.item').length;

    function shift(direction) {
        var $mask = $('#mask'),
            $items = $('.item'),
            currentItem = $mask.data('currentItem');

        if (currentItem === undefined) {
            currentItem = 0;
        }

        $mask.data('currentItem', newItem).animate({
            marginLeft: -newItem * $items.eq(0).width()
        });
    }

    $('#prev').click(function () {
        if (newItem === 0) {
            newItem = itemCount - 1;
        } else {
            newItem--;
        }
        return shift();
    });
    $('#next').click(function () {
        if (newItem === itemCount - 1) {
            newItem = 0;
        } else {
            newItem++;
        }
        return shift();
    });

    function resizePanel() {
        width = $(window).width();
        height = $(window).height();

        $('#wrapper').css({
            width: width,
            height: height
        });

        $('.item').css({
            width: width - 100,
            height: height
        });
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizePanel();
    });
    resizePanel();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just looking at what your resizePanel() function is doing, could you not just use CSS?

For instance,

```
#wrapper{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 50px; // recreate the width - 100 for .item
}
.item{
 width: 100%;
}
```

Also if possible i would leverage CSS transforms/transitions as this will really improve your animation performance over using margin-left.

As for your problem with the images appearing, it does not seem like you hide the non active .item elements.

Try setting,

```
.item{
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 transition: .2s;
}
```

Then when you show a .item add a class like,

```
.item-active{
 opacity: 1
 visibility: visible;
}
```